# Reflect on Clojure Function Name

Tags: function, reflection, clojure

How do I use reflection in Clojure to extract the function name of a symbol that evaluates to a function?

```
(require '[clojure.reflect :as r])
(defn foo [x] x)
(r/reflect foo)
=> {#clojure.reflect.Field ... 'gobbledygook}
```

Something about `(map :name (:members (r/reflect foo)))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get function's name as string in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116257/how-to-get-functions-name-as-string-in-clojure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, please do not use `str` because it behaves differently. In my example, here is what I've got:

```
user=> (defn foo [x] x)
#'user/foo
user=> (str foo)
"user$foo@7cb20059"
```

Instead, use combination of `meta` and `var` calls:

```
(-> foo var meta)
```

This code returns a map of variable's metadata. The key `:name` holds the function name as a string:

```
(-> foo var meta :name)
foo
```

If you also want to have an ns's name, do the following:

```
user=> (-> foo var meta :ns ns-name)
user
```

It gets the namespace object and returns its name with the `ns-name` function as a string.

Those methods do not depend on Clojure or REPL version and thus are more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use `str`:

```
(str foo)
=> "#'my-project/foo"
```